# How to add a component into a elementref?

Tags: angular

I want to add a component into a elementref as a child and have access to it's properties.

```
const element: HTMLElement = document.createElement('div');

element.innerHTML = // Component needs to be added here

// Need to have access to properties of the Component here
```

I have added a Full Calendar to my project and for the timeline i need to add custom resource Elements. For this i only get access to the HTMLElement and some data. So What i want to do is pass an intialised component to the HTMLElement.

Right now my only option is writing the html as the string and passing it to the innerHTML. Is there a better Option?

Comment: can you explain more?

Comment: What is ur requirment ? What you wanna do is not possible.

Comment: Can you give an alternative is possible

Comment: you can look into https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader and https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-dynamically-create-a-component-in-angular

Comment: Tried it but did not work @Caro

Comment: @Caro is right. You should use dynamic component creation, that's exactly its purpose. If you tried and couldn't get it to work, I suggest you post your attempt and let us try to help you fix it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In one of my projects, I achieved something similar to your requirement this way. Let me know if it helps?

```js
constructor(private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver,
            private injector: Injector, 
            private appRef: ApplicationRef) {
  const componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(DynamicComponent); // Your dynamic component will replace DynamicComponent

  const componentRef = componentFactory.create(this.injector);

  this.appRef.attachView(componentRef.hostView);  

  const domElem = (componentRef.hostView as EmbeddedViewRef<any>).rootNodes[0] as HTMLElement;

  const element: HTMLElement = document.createElement('div');
  element.appendChild(domElem); // Component needs to be added here
  document.body.appendChild(element);
}
```

This way you will have reference to your dynamic component as `componentRef`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I can access the instance using the componentRef. Right?

Comment: @SachithRukshan yes

Comment: To get the domElem we can use `componentRef.location.nativeElement;`

Answer (score 6):

You might be able to use [Renderer2](https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2)

```
export class AppComponent { 
@ViewChild('addButton') 
  private animateThis: ElementRef;  
  constructor(private renderer: Renderer2) {}

  addBtn() {
    const button = this.renderer.createElement('button'); 
    const buttonText = this.renderer.createText('This is a button');
    this.renderer.appendChild(button, buttonText);
    this.renderer.appendChild(this.animateThis.nativeElement, button);
  }
}
```

[More examples](https://itnext.io/using-renderer2-in-angular-8f80da6756f8)

Comment: Thanks for the answer but i have checked this solution before. And it does not make it any easier. And y is it better than HTMLElement

Comment: It is better because now angular is aware of the DOM change. By just appending it to the DOM angular is unaware of it.

Comment: What is the exact advantage of it.

Comment: I literally just explained

Comment: I have already implemented the inner elements of the elemenrref and added business logics too.so what i need to know is whether adding renderer2 will make it any easier

Answer (score 1):

[The Angular documentation](https://angular.io/guide/elements) says

> *Angular elements* are Angular components packaged as *custom elements* (also called Web Components)

Thus, you can create the element you want to add using

1. `document.createElement('elementName')` if it is an [autonomous custom element](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/custom-elements.html#custom-elements-autonomous-example), or
2. `document.createElement('baseElementName', {is: 'elementName'})` if it is a [customized built-in element](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/custom-elements.html#custom-elements-customized-builtin-example).

You can insert the element you created into a `container` element using `container.insertAdjacentElement(position, element)` as explained [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentElement).

Comment: That was exactly what I have done but what i want to know is a better solution. Please read the question properly

Comment: @SachithRukshan I believe this is quite different to `writing the html as the string and passing it to the innerHTML`

Answer (score 0):

```
import { AfterContentInit, Component, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    template: `
    <h1>My App</h1>
    <pre>
      <code>{{ node }}</code>
    </pre>
  `
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterContentInit {
  node: string;

  constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) { }

  ngAfterContentInit() {
    const tmp = document.createElement('div');
    const el = this.elementRef.nativeElement.cloneNode(true);

    tmp.appendChild(el);
    this.node = tmp.innerHTML;
  }

}
```

Comment: I found this when I did some dogging. Hope you find it useful

Comment: Hi Amrish, Thank you for trying to help out. Can Explain a bit about how it might help my problem.

Comment: @AmrishkhanSheik Hi, welcome to Stackoverflow. When you post an answer, it's advised that you provide an explanation as well. Just a code fence does not explain why or how this is pertinent to the answer. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

given that the component is registered in window.customElements,
and according to the Angular documentation it probably is,
you could do:

```
var element = document.createElement("div");

var comp= document.createElement("your-component")
/*
optionally set component attributes or anything else
you also have access to the component's properties here
comp.setAttribute("name",value)
console.log(comp.exampleProperty)
*/
element.appendChild(comp)
```